# Store notification object on shared preferences

Tags: android, json, serialization, gson, android-notifications

I'm running into problems when I try to save a notification object.
I have try serialization (but notification is not serializable) use parcels with no luck, and then I found a promising way: GSON

But after several problems implementing and including the library I am stuck again.

This code seems to work fine:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(notification);
```

But when I try to build the notification object back it crashes:

```
Notification notification = gson.fromJson(json, Notification.class);
```

This is the crash log:

```
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.example.hello/org.example.hello.Hello}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private android.widget.RemoteViews$Action() with no args
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3014)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3055)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private android.widget.RemoteViews$Action() with no args
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:107)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:162)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at ie.elementsoftware.WaveNotification.setCustomNotification(WaveNotification.java:92)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at org.example.hello.Hello.onResume(Hello.java:94)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1266)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5148)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2997)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    ... 12 more
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class android.widget.RemoteViews$Action
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:104)
    07-03 13:13:55.930: E/AndroidRuntime(12324):    ... 29 more
```

Am I missing something? Or just I cannot convert android classes to JSON?
If the problem is that, have I got another way to store the object rather than manually store each possible argument contained on a notification object?

Thanks!

Comment: 'It crashes' is too vague a description of the error you are running into. What exact stacktrace do you get when trying to execute the line `Notification notification = gson.fromJson(json, Notification.class);`?

Comment: Sorry, edited with the error log...

Comment: The problem is occurring because an Android class (`android.widget.RemoteViews$Action`) without a default constructor is included in the serialization chain. Do you have access to the source for `ie.elementsoftware.WaveNotification`?

Comment: Yes, I do. It's part of my code. That's the class where I want to make the serialization and de-serialization of the notification.